# Groovy Working with Lists and ranges

Tags: groovy

I am trying to get myself started with Groovy, I am trying to find out the numbers within 1 to 100 that are divisible by 7.

```
def numbers=[1..100]
def divisibleBy7 = numbers.findAll {it % 7 == 0 }
divisibleBy7.each{println it}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong. The error message from groovy console is not very clear

```
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.IntRange.mod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [7]
Possible solutions: pop(), min(), max(), add(java.lang.Object), add(java.lang.Object), add(int, java.lang.Object)
    at divisibleBy7$_run_closure1.doCall(divisibleBy7.groovy:2)
    at divisibleBy7.run(divisibleBy7.groovy:2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with [1..100]. The square brackets are the syntax for a list.  Therefore, this is a list of IntRange instead of the range itself. What you want is:

```
def numbers = 1..100
def divisibleBy7 = numbers.findAll {it % 7 == 0 }
divisibleBy7.each{println it}
```

You can also use parens around ranges.

Comment: Thanks @jstrater. Correct me I'm wrong def numbers=1..100 gives me a list containing numbers from 1 to 100. So def numbers=1..100 is equivalent to def numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....,100]

Comment: @mahtab-alam You're welcome. That is mostly correct.  Ranges are an extension of list.  When you do a findAll or .each it will behave the same as the list. You can even try `1..5 == [1,2,3,4,5]` in the groovy console and it returns true; however, `(1..5).class == [1,2,3,4,5].class` will be false. For more info see the [docs for Range](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/IntRange.html)